# Rails secret token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I'm quite confused what is secret_token used for in Rails.  Can anyone explain what it is used for?  Is it OK to put this token in a public source repository and use it in production, or I should change it before deploying my app to prevent some kinds of attacks?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Answering my own question - secret_token is used to prevent cookie tampering in Rails.  Every cookie has a checksum saved with it, so users won't modify cookie contents (and change saved user id to steal someone's account, for example).  The checksum is based on cookie contents and secret_token, so if you are using cookie based sessions you should always make sure your secret_token is really secret, otherwise you can't trust that anything you put into session came back unchanged.