# What is the use of secret_token in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I today tried out the rail's tutorial and was confused over this part of generating secret-code.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top

```
require 'securerandom'

def secure_token
  token_file = Rails.root.join('.secret')
  if File.exist?(token_file)
    # Use the existing token.
    File.read(token_file).chomp
  else
    # Generate a new token and store it in token_file.
    token = SecureRandom.hex(64)
    File.write(token_file, token)
    token
  end
end

SampleApp::Application.config.secret_token = secure_token
```

Can anyone explain me what is the need of this file. What is the purpose of this 64 bit generated secret string.

Comment: It appears to be used to mitigate tampering (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241441/rails-secret-token) via some form of HMAC. This is useful because it increase confidence that data from the client (in cookies, or even in hidden field) has *only* been generated by the particular server and can thus be used safely. I am not sure if RoR also guards against replay attacks with this approach, however.

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the comments of that file:

> Your secret key is used for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.

Signed cookies are used to store session info or what else you want to allocate to user and only that user.

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) for more info on sessions and cookies.